# Is it possible to make money with ads if you have few users?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, ads, interstitial

Hello everyone let's say I just published my app at the App Store and set some interstitial ads from Ads mob, If first ”app downloader” or user sees my ad will I make money or there is some kind of fixed quantity of users from where I can make some income? Or maybe it depends on another things which I do not know, please tell me about that advertisement stuff))

Comment: This question isn't about programming and should be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about "Google AdMob" (not "Ads mob"), then according to Google, "As a publisher, you'll earn revenue each time a CPM ad is served to your app and viewed by a user."  https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3436338?hl=en

However, typical rates seem to be $1-5 CPM (per THOUSAND views), so you can't make very much money unless you have lots of activity on your app.

Comment: Please do not respond to off-topic questions, post a comment instead.